# Why doesnt localhost ever work on windows 10?

Tags: xampp, localhost, windows-10

Ive got a brand new machine (Lenovo Y700) running Windows 10. I have xampp installed and I have my project folder in the htdocs folder of my xampp install as well. For some reason, no matter what I do, I cannot figure out why my project does not display. All I ever get is an "Index Of" page. Basically just a file hierarchy of my project folder. When changing URL to a specific path within that folder, I get directed to a page saying "refused to connect". I have uninstalled and re-installed xampp 5 or 6 times and I just cannot figure out why I cant view my project on the localhost. Makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Is your Apache server running?

Comment: Additionally, I have also tried changing port numbers thinking another app was using port 80 but after checking, nothing is using Port 80. I dont even have skype on this machine. On another note, I dont have "World Wide Web" in my services list either. (I've seen people suggest this as a fix to remove it but this machine doesnt even have it)

Comment: yes both apache and mysql

Comment: You tried run php info in www folder or connection is always refused?

Comment: Check the firewall settings? I had a problem similar to this.

Comment: I tried the firewall thing last night, turned it off for an hour. Still kept displaying "Index Of" page instead of displaying my project itself.

Comment: Might be a silly question but do you have an index.html or index.php file?

Comment: Do you see anything in the apache log file?